# Vf Page on lightning home page giving error

Tags: visualforce, permissions, lightning-apps, lightning, lightning-experience

I have created a VF page to display Feeds on lightning home page.

```html
<apex:page showHeader="false" sidebar="false" >
  <chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}"/>
</apex:page>
```

this page is enabled for lightning. 
When I log in as admin I am not getting any error.
But I have a custom profile assigned to the user. I have enabled Vf page to this user.

But when I login as this user I am getting an error for this page.
Error is

> "The page no longer exists. Try reloading it. If the problem persists, contact Salesforce support."

How should I resolve this, I have given permission to this page then too I am getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the custom profile assigned to user has access to User records (Read permission on User object)

Comment: Actually I thought of the same, So I commented  <chatter:feed entityId="{!$User.Id}"/> this line and tried to refresh my page using non admin user. But got the same error.

Comment: Also I have created a VF tab and assigned a tab to user. On click of this tab I can get the page with no errors on it. 
But on lightning home page i get the  above error.

Answer (score 0):

Enable "View Setup and Configuration" for profile.
https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000IXstQAG

You can enable View Setup and Configuration as
Select the profile --> Administrative Permissions --> View Setup and Configuration